# Feature encoding for multiple JSON objects

Tags: feature-engineering, anomaly-detection

I have a dataset, where a particular feature is a collection of many JSON objects for a single feature.

```
Timestamp    Observations
1            {"name":"bob", "place":"TX"},{"name":"ann", "place":"NY"},{"name":"jack", "place":"MA"},{"name":"jill", "place":"CA"}
2            {"name":"bob", "place":"TX"},{"name":"ann", "place":"NY"},{"name":"jack", "place":"MA"},{"name":"jill", "place":"CA"}, {"name":"darth", "place":"XX"}
```

How can I encode the Observations feature for each tuple, so that I can use it to do some sort of anomaly detection? (Note that for the second tuple, there is an extra JSON object)

Comment: Do you have a bounded number of persons (names)? How many possible different places are there?